# AngularJS - $http 200 but no data?

Tags: angularjs, http, response

Using `firefox` `REST` client I can get the response object back and a 200 success. But in my app, my preflight gets a 200 and then the `GET` call fails?

How can I debug this?

Here's firefox restclient response (there is a `json` object in the response body:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mre2V.png

Here's my app code:

```
$http({
     url: 'http://api.stubhub.com/search/catalog/events/v2?title="san"',
     dataType: 'json',
     method: 'GET',
     data: '',
     headers: {
         "Content-Type": 'application/json',
         "Authorization": 'Bearer {token}'
     }
}).success(function(response) {
        $scope.searchResponse = response;
}).error(function(error) {
        $scope.error = error;
});
```

Here's what I get in chrome:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5b22.png

My authorization token is correct. I have a feeling this is angulars default headers are interfering with my GET call but I don't know what it could be or a browser related issue. I've tried restangular but no luck. Any ideas?

EDIT1: Apparantly the 200 code is on the preflight OPTIONS GET. I'm getting this in the browser console:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.stubhub.com/search/catalog/events/v2?title=%22san%22. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://127.0.0.1:9000' is therefore not allowed access.
```

but when I do this in firefox I get the same thing except in the response I'm seeing the content-length as if there was a response. The response just isn't there.

Comment: I would suggest adding a debugger statement in your success callback and see what the value is of the response parameter.  See if it contains what you expect and, if not, what does it reference?

Comment: I did that and it's actually only 200 code on the options (preflight) call. It's not even hitting the .success callback when I console log after .success

Comment: You can't preflight GET request

Comment: PS, it's really weird that a URL GET parameters would have "san", check that as well.

Comment: @Linial I removed the "" and tried it with integers and other strings still getting the error. Works in firefox rest client though :(

Comment: Looks like a CORS issue. The pre-flight OPTIONS request is typically handled by Angular and/or the browser (I think). It is super annoying. As long as the API supports it, it'll send a pre-flight response with acceptable paths, methods, headers, etc... But then I was under the impression your original request would be sent (as long as it matches the pre-flight response acceptable pieces).

Comment: according to error you need to allow-origin: *

Comment: @Linial it says that that's not allowed

Comment: I'll ask you just for this small thing, Open up plnkr.co, type down only the part of the $http request with the same API, and see if that problem occurs or not.

Comment: @Linial I'm getting a 403 on the OPTIONS now.

Here's plnkr : http://plnkr.co/edit/BIiw24?p=preview

Comment: Can you try do the same thing with writing the token explicitly? also use hurl.it to test your backend.

Comment: @Linial Hey sorry, I meant to the have the token in there. http://plnkr.co/edit/BIiw24?p=preview  try again. It's a 403

Comment: Please debug the problem here : hurl.it .. I can't make single API tool.. I'm talking about backend problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64650/discussion-between-garuuk-and-linial).